# Question about finite extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

A hint to an exercise in my textbook says "Since $B/F$ is finite, it is algebraic, and there are elements $α_1,...,α_n$ with $B=F(α_1,...,α_n)$."

I understand that if $B/F$ is a finite extension then $B$ is algebraic. But why does $B$ being algebraic imply that $B=F(α_1,...,α_n)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $B$ being algebraic does actually not imply that! These are two separate implications. Namely, a) finite implies algebraic and b) finite implies generated by finitely many elements. For b), think about what "finite" means.

Comment: @Thorgott Ah so its just because B as an F-vector space is spanned by finitely many elements?

Comment: Indeed, the point is that a set of elements generating the extension as a vector space implies that it also generates it as a field extension (the latter condition is weaker than the former).